# Using cutwin package to get a "flowing text" effect

Tags: luatex, cutwin

I am trying to get a flowing text effect using the Latex Package cutwin. I adjusted the example from the documentation but am stuck with hanging text in the right margin.

Here is my minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\mycut}{
0.95\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.9\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.85\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.8\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.75\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.7\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.7\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.7\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.7\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.75\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.8\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.85\textwidth, 0\textwidth,
0.9\textwidth, 0\textwidth
}
\begin{shapedcutout}{5}{13}{\mycut}
\lipsum[1]           
\lipsum[1]               
\end{shapedcutout}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

As you can see there is overflowing text in the right hand margin. I have tried several hacks involving the 'hfil', 'hbadness', 'raggedright', 'flushleft',  to try and get it to start a new line, but to no avail.

Maybe someone here sees something I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out. I just needed to explicitly tell it to be in the 'opencutright' environment with the correct number of entries.

Here is the correct code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\emergencystretch 40em
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\mycut}{
0.95\textwidth,
0.9\textwidth, 
0.85\textwidth,
0.8\textwidth,
0.75\textwidth,
0.7\textwidth,
0.7\textwidth,
0.7\textwidth,
0.7\textwidth,
0.75\textwidth,
0.8\textwidth,
0.85\textwidth,
0.9\textwidth
}
\opencutright
\begin{shapedcutout}{5}{13}{\mycut}
\lipsum[1]           
\lipsum[1]               
\end{shapedcutout}
\end{document}
```

And the correct output:

[image]

I figured it out almost immediately after posting my question. Not sure on the etiquette but will keep this question here in case someone else makes the same silly mistake I did.